# How to pass a list into another function and then make a list of lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a function called `labeled` that basically scans the first character of each element in a list and returns only those elements with hashtags. So far I have gotten that function down. However I need a function after that that takes the list from the original function and then counts how many times that value appears in the list. So let's say the user inputs `"I really like hot cheetos #good #yum #yum"`, I would need to take that string, let the first function return the list of the hashtags and then a second function to return something like `['yum',2,'good',1]`. This is what I have now:

```
 def labeled(x):
    x = input("Enter a sentence or quit: ")
    if x == 'quit':
        return "Bye"
    labeled_list = []
    for word in x.split():
        if word [0] == "#":
            labeled_list.append(word[1:])
    for hashtags in labeled_list:
        return labeled_list      
print(labeled())
def tabulated(labeled_list):
```

Comment: "collections.Counter" produces nearly what you want but as a kind of dictionary instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is the way to go for all your frequency counting needs and you can extract hashtags reasonably well with `re.findall(r"(?:^|\s)#(\w+)", s)`.

Having said that, the desired output structure seems suboptimal to me. Finding the frequency of a word requires a linear search and then a potentially crashing `index + 1` operation and iterating it is awkward. I'd prefer a dictionary which is pretty much what `Counter` gives you, or at least a list of tuple word-frequency pairs. The below code shows how to get a `Counter` and then transform the data into progressively (probably?) less useful structures:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "I really like hot cheetos #good #yum #yum"
>>> tags = re.findall(r"(?:^|\s)#(\w+)", s)
>>> tags
['good', 'yum', 'yum']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(tags)
Counter({'yum': 2, 'good': 1})
>>> [x for x in Counter(tags).most_common()]
[('yum', 2), ('good', 1)]
>>> [y for x in Counter(tags).most_common() for y in x]
['yum', 2, 'good', 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it, using list comprehensions and collections.Counter.

```
>>> import collections
>>> t = "I really like hot cheetos #good #yum #yum"
>>> l = [w.replace('#') for w in t.split() if w[0] == '#']
>>> collections.Counter(l)
Counter({'#yum': 2, '#good': 1})
```

This is a simplistic way to do it, but if you have simple needs then this might do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The modification is trivial (w.replace...)